# Create a Wordpress JSON API controller for user search (based on xprofile and user plus plugin)

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, search

I develop a mobile front-end with API functions in javascript (jQuery framework).

How do I create a JSON API controller for user search?

I'm using the Wordpress [JSON API User Plus](http://www.parorrey.com/solutions/json-api-user-plus/) and I want to search in xprofile fields.

How can I do it?